# Discord Bot sending multiple embeds instead of one when using data from mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

Hey so i wrote a discord bot for a minecraft server that is ment to display the top 10 playtimes for players on the server. but instead of it sending one embed it sends 10 embeds, one for each player in the 10 rows i queryed any help would be appresiated!

```js
var now = new Date();
var playtimes = '../cost of ballin/PLAYTIMES/playtime-' + now.getFullYear() + "-" + now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate() + '.txt'

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content == prefix + "pt") {
        con.query("SELECT DAYS,NAME,MINUTES,HOURS FROM playtimes ORDER BY DAYS DESC LIMIT 10",
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                    var row = result[key];
                    fs.appendFileSync(playtimes, "Player Name: " + row.NAME + " Days: " + row.DAYS + " Hours: " + row.HOURS + " Minutes: " + row.MINUTES + "\r\n")
                    var file = fs.readFileSync(playtimes)
                    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#000000')
                        .setTitle('Playtime Leaderboard')
                        .setDescription(playtimes)
                    wait(10000)
                    channel.send(embed);
                })

            }
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem i see here is that you are doing `channel.send()` each time your `.forEach()` loop runs.

This sends a message each time you run through it. what you should do instead, is create some sort of object that stores the stats you get from your queries, and then send the message after the `.forEach()` loop has finished. for example:

```
var now = new Date();
var playtimes = '../cost of ballin/PLAYTIMES/playtime-' + now.getFullYear() + "-" + now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate() + '.txt'

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content == prefix + "pt") {

        let playTimeStats = {} //create a dictionary for the stats

        con.query("SELECT DAYS,NAME,MINUTES,HOURS FROM playtimes ORDER BY DAYS DESC LIMIT 10",
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                    var row = result[key];
                    fs.appendFileSync(playtimes, "Player Name: " + row.NAME + " Days: " + row.DAYS + " Hours: " + row.HOURS + " Minutes: " + row.MINUTES + "\r\n")
                    var file = fs.readFileSync(playtimes)
    
                    playTimeStats[row.NAME] = {
                        "Days": row.DAYS,
                        "Hours": row.HOURS,
                        "Minutes": row.MINUTES
                    } //add the stats to the dictionary                   

                })
            }
        );

//make an embed here for the stats, and then send it

    }
});
```

I haven't written all the code for you, but I have added what I think you need to get you started... I've added the dictionary and how to add elements to it, you just need to make and send the embed.

Comment: so i followed the code written and am now having a issue where it is putting [object, Object] in the area where the playTimeStats output is ment to be, probably just me misunderstanding things because i just recently started to learn node, thanks for all the help you have given thus far!

Comment: Since it is in an object, what you need to do is parse the object. you can find docs on how to parse these [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) under `accessing object properties`.  If I were you, I would probably loop through the object using a `for()` loop and adding the properties to the embed as i see them. (info on for loops [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp))